# dhcp on virtual interface

Tags: linux-networking, dhcp

I want to configure two IP address on a single network interface. One static and one DHCP. I would prefer to have static on eth0 and dhcp on eth0:1. But as the both eth0 and eth0:1 share the same mac address, the dhcp never gets an IP. It would be better if anyone who has done this, could share some thought on how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: add another virtual interface to your machine. you will have a different mac address. and you will be able to configure dhcp on this new mac.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply, but my ifconfig shows the same `HWaddr` for both `eth1` and `eth1:1` as far as I understood to get dhcp on `eth1:1` it need to have a different  `HWaddr` ??

Comment: you did not read my comment. ethX and ethX:1 is the same virtual nic ethX, so same mac address. add another virtual interface to have ethX and ethY on your system.

Comment: ok I got your point. But actually I want to achieve both static and DHCP on one interface like, ethX - static and ethX:1 as dynamic if possible?

Comment: I think it is possible to have dhcp assignement for ethX, and then create a systemd unit to add static ip alias on ethX:1. You should also describe globally what you want to achieve, and not the solution you believe in. You would be surprised how people can have very good ideas.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I should elaborate more on my question and then listen to the ideas and ways to implement it. I'll update my question.

Comment: hi, i used dnsmasq with ip binding so it only listen on ip instead a device